# Problem with masterpage

Tags: asp.net, web-config, navigation

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AdventureWorks" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AdventureWorksLT2008_Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>



  <system.web>
    <pages masterPageFile="Navigation.master"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The Virtual path "Navigation.master" is not allowed here..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it depends, what would you like to do? why you placed master page into configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/950xf363.aspx), `masterPageFile` attribute:

> Specifies the master page path
>   relative to the local configuration
>   file.

So, you have to specify a relative path.  For example, something like this:

```
<pages masterPageFile="~/Navigation.master"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

˜/something.master